# Jupyter Spark database access; java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: python, mysql, apache-spark, jdbc, docker

I am using Python 2.7 & Spark 2.0.2 in a jupyter notebook trying to access a mySql database in another docker container. I have implemented just about everything I can find to remedy the issue and still coming up short. [This](http://www.prcconsulting.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Connect_MySQL.py_-1.html) is my model, so at least similar has been done before. I put my notebook and Dockerfile in a public repository for reference, in the 'mysql' branch, [here](https://github.com/Archethought/docker-jupyter-spark2/tree/mysql).

Code that fails:

```
df = (spark.read.format('jdbc')
      .options(
        url='jdbc:mysql://172.17.0.8:6603/giskard',
        user='root',
        password='datascience',
        dbtable='supers',driver='com.mysql.jdbc.Driver')
      .load()
     )
```

with (excerpt, full list in the notebook referenced above):

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o42.load.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
```

Inside the dockerfile, I added all possible solutions I found:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends apt-utils && \
    apt-get install -y mysql-client     && \
    apt-get install -y python-dev       && \
    apt-get install -y libmysqlclient-dev   && \
    apt-get install -y libmysql-java        && \
    apt-get clean

RUN pip2 install MySQL-python
```

I verified the mysql jar file exists inside the container and then added it to SPARK_OPTS such that a `%env` inside the notebook yeilds:

```
'SPARK_OPTS': '--driver-java-options=-Xms1024M --driver-java-options=-Xmx4096M --driver-java-options=-Dlog4j.logLevel=info --spark-jars=/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar',
```

other possible relevant parts of the environment:

```
 'PATH': '/opt/conda/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin',
 'PYSPARK_PYTHON': '/opt/conda/envs/python2/bin/python',
 'PYTHONPATH': '/usr/local/spark/python:/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip:/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 'SPARK_HOME': '/usr/local/spark',
```

The database I'm trying to reach does exist with data. The process I used is documented in the first cell of my notebook. Am I making this too complicated? What am I missing and what else can I try? I appreciate any direction you can offer towards a solution!

Comment: `mysql-connector-java.jars` probably a typo, it is usually `jar` (without an **s**), and usually has a version number in it.

Comment: Thank you, Mark. I corrected the typo; unfortunately it had no effect on the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the issue(s) by stepping back to see if I could access the database just through python and checking the spark process inside the container with `ps -aux`

1) all containers must be on the same network to communicate; linking is apparently not enough. I used a new one:
`docker network create --driver bridge dbnet`

2) I installed `python-mysqldb` to access the database via python. I did this within the notebook instead of adding it to the dockerfile.

```
!sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y python-mysqldb

# from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/1.2.5
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(host=DB_SERVER_IP,     # your host, usually localhost
                     user=MYSQL_USER,       # your username
                     passwd=MYSQL_PASSWORD, # your password
                     db=MYSQL_DATABASE)     # name of the data base
```

3) Spark needed `libmysql-java` and for the jar file to be copied to `/usr/local/spark/jars`. Far as I can tell, the docker SPARK_OPTS setting is ineffective. I added to the Dockerfile:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends apt-utils && \
    apt-get install -y libmysql-java            && \
    apt-get clean
RUN ln -s /usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar /usr/local/spark/jars
```

And now all is well. I'll leave the sample notebook in the mysql branch of the [spark 2 docker repository](https://github.com/Archethought/docker-jupyter-spark2/tree/mysql) should anyone else need my exact steps.